# How to pass variables from one function to another or combine functions

Tags: functions, theme-customizer, wp-enqueue-style

I have two functions:

- 1st - Takes care of all customizer options
- 2nd - Generates an inline style from those options

In first function I set variables from which I create customizer settings and controls like this:

```
function im_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {

//Custom Sections

$wp_customize->add_section(
    'body',
    array(
        'title'     => __('Body Settings', 'impressive'),
        'priority'  => 200
    )
);

//Styles

$bg_color = 'background-color:';
$max_width = 'max-width:';

$styles = array();

$styles[] = array(
  'slug'=>'body_bcolor', 
  'default' => "#F1F2F1",
  'label' => __('Body Background Color', 'impressive'),
  'css_class' => 'body',
  'attribute' => $bg_color,
  'section' => 'body',
  'type' => 'color'
);
$styles[] = array(
  'slug'=>'max_container_width', 
  'default' => '1440',
  'label' => __('Maximal Container Width', 'impressive'),
  'css_class' => '.header',
  'attribute' => $max_width,
  'section' => 'body',
  'type' => 'number'
);

foreach( $styles as $style ) {

  $wp_customize->add_setting(
    $style['slug'], array(
      'default' => $style['default'],
      'type' => 'option', 
      'capability' => 
      'edit_theme_options'
    )
  );

 if ( $style['type'] == 'color' ) {
  $wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Color_Control(
      $wp_customize,
      $style['slug'], 
      array('label' => $style['label'],
      'section' => $style['section'],
      'settings' => $style['slug'],
      'type' => $style['type'])
    )
  );
  } elseif ( $style['type'] == 'image' && $style['section'] == 'header_image' ) {
    $wp_customize->add_control(
        new WP_Customize_Header_Image_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        $style['slug'], 
        array('section' => $style['section'],
        'settings' => $style['slug'])
    )
  );
 } else {
  $wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Control(
      $wp_customize,
      $style['slug'], 
      array('label' => $style['label'],
      'section' => $style['section'],
      'settings' => $style['slug'],
      'type' => $style['type'])
    )
  );

  }

}

}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'im_customize_register' );
```

In second function I need to type same variables in order for the script to generate inline CSS:

```
function im_custom_style_create() {

wp_enqueue_style( 'im_custom_style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/im_custom_style.css' );

$custom_css = '';

$bg_color = 'background-color:';
$max_width = 'max-width:';

$measurement_unit = '';

$styles = array();

$styles[] = array(
  'slug'=>'body_bcolor', 
  'default' => "#F1F2F1",
  'label' => __('Body Background Color', 'impressive'),
  'css_class' => 'body',
  'attribute' => $bg_color,
  'section' => 'body',
  'type' => 'color'
);
$styles[] = array(
  'slug'=>'max_container_width', 
  'default' => '1440',
  'label' => __('Maximal Container Width', 'impressive'),
  'css_class' => '.header',
  'attribute' => $max_width,
  'section' => 'body',
  'type' => 'number'
);

foreach( $styles as $style ) {

if ( $style['attribute'] == $max_width ) { $measurement_unit = 'px'; }

if ( get_option( $style['slug'] ) == true ) { $custom_css = '' . $style['css_class'] . ' { ' . $style['attribute'] . ' ' . get_option( $style['slug'] ) . $measurement_unit . '; } '; };

wp_add_inline_style ('im_custom_style', $custom_css);
}

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'im_custom_style_create' );
```

My question is: Is there is a way to pass `$styles` from 1st function to 2nd or is there isn't one can I combine those two function. I tried combining them but I couldn't make the magic happen.

Comment: Just put both functions into the same class. That's what objects are for: combining state and behavior.

Comment: @toscho It should be in a class, but it's not required to do what he's asking. What you have said isn't a solution.

Comment: @SteveNorth It solves the problem in the most efficient and least fragile way.

Comment: @toscho It solves the issue with bad practice, yeah. But, i'm not convinced he even needs to combine any functions. It looks to me like he's trying to do the same thing twice for 2 different reasons when i'm sure it could be combined into a single function.

Comment: @SteveNorth Re-read what I have written here and in the duplicate. No one says, both functions should be "combined". They should act in the same **scope**, namely that of an object. *you* suggested to create a static dependency on elements from the global namespace. That is very wordpressy, but still bad practice.

Comment: @toscho Combining two functions would be a last resort. I'd prefer if could reuse same variables in two different separate functions. Plus I organized them in two separate PHP files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways that would be the most simple.

1. Do it with a function call.
2. Make the variables global.

The first would be done like so:

```
function my_func() {
    $styles = 'stuff';

    second_func($styles);
}

function second_func($styles) {
    // do something with $styles
    var_dump($styles);
}
```

The second way would be done like so:

```
// Set global variable
$GLOBALS['styles'] = 'stuff';


// Call it anywhere else
global $styles;
```

For more on globals:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

EDIT: See below.

```
global $styles;

$styles = array(
  array(
    'slug'=>'body_bcolor', 
    'default' => "#F1F2F1",
    'label' => __('Body Background Color', 'impressive'),
    'css_class' => 'body',
    'attribute' => 'background-color:',
    'section' => 'body',
    'type' => 'color'
  ),
  array(
  'slug'=>'max_container_width', 
  'default' => '1440',
  'label' => __('Maximal Container Width', 'impressive'),
  'css_class' => '.header',
  'attribute' => 'max-width:',
  'section' => 'body',
  'type' => 'number'
  )
);


function im_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
global $styles;
//Custom Sections

$wp_customize->add_section(
    'body',
    array(
        'title'     => __('Body Settings', 'impressive'),
        'priority'  => 200
    )
);

foreach( $GLOBALS['styles'] as $style ) {

  $wp_customize->add_setting(
    $style['slug'], array(
      'default' => $style['default'],
      'type' => 'option', 
      'capability' => 
      'edit_theme_options'
    )
  );

 if ( $style['type'] == 'color' ) {
  $wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Color_Control(
      $wp_customize,
      $style['slug'], 
      array('label' => $style['label'],
      'section' => $style['section'],
      'settings' => $style['slug'],
      'type' => $style['type'])
    )
  );
  } elseif ( $style['type'] == 'image' && $style['section'] == 'header_image' ) {
    $wp_customize->add_control(
        new WP_Customize_Header_Image_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        $style['slug'], 
        array('section' => $style['section'],
        'settings' => $style['slug'])
    )
  );
 } else {
  $wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Control(
      $wp_customize,
      $style['slug'], 
      array('label' => $style['label'],
      'section' => $style['section'],
      'settings' => $style['slug'],
      'type' => $style['type'])
    )
  );

  }

}

}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'im_customize_register' );


function im_custom_style_create() {
global $styles;

wp_enqueue_style( 'im_custom_style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/im_custom_style.css' );

foreach( $styles as $style ) {

if ( $style['attribute'] == $max_width ) { $measurement_unit = 'px'; }

if ( get_option( $style['slug'] ) == true ) { $custom_css = '' . $style['css_class'] . ' { ' . $style['attribute'] . ' ' . get_option( $style['slug'] ) . $measurement_unit . '; } '; };

wp_add_inline_style ('im_custom_style', $custom_css);
}

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'im_custom_style_create' );
```

Comment: `my_func()` is supposed to be my first function right?

Comment: Yeah that's right.

Comment: The two brackets at the end of a function name can be used to pass in arguments. The arguments can be pretty much any type. You may want to read up on PHP functions and how to do this for a better explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer however neither way worked in the context of my functions. I am probably doing something wrong.

Comment: In my second function it gives me a FOREACH error for the first method. Second just doesn't work

Comment: Well first up you need to remove $styles = array(); in second function.

Comment: You are overwriting the variable with nothing otherwise. Use var_dump($var) to see what's in a variable for better way of debugging.

Comment: I am away from my PC but I believe I already tried to remove array();. That's when I get foreach error. With array it obviously doesn't output anything. Also those two functions are in separate php files included in functions.php. Could that cause a problem?

Comment: Only if you haven't included that other file for access.

Comment: Nope they are both included. Could the order in which they are included affect it? I believe file with second function included before file with first

Comment: Edit your question to exactly what your function 1 and 2 have and I'll write it for you.

Comment: As soon as I get home I'll update it

Comment: Updated it with full code

Comment: See edited code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46711/discussion-between-erdfx-and-steve-north).